# Resizing HTML widget in Jive

Tags: javascript, iframe, jive

In JiveX I have a HTML widget that uses javascript to check to see if the logged in user is a member of a permission group. This causes the widget to render in an iframe. The JS conditionally hides / shows content but this happens after the iframe has rendered and Jive has calculated its height.

What is the best way to tell Jive to resize the iframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jive has a built in javascript function called `resizeMe();` I was able to fix this issue by calling `resizeMe()` in a callback from my own JS code. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you mark your own answer correct? I can't remember if stackoverflow allows that for everyone.